# Use regex for change arguments count

Tags: objective-c, regex, xcode, methods, replace

I am new in using regex.

I am trying to change arguments count in my method. In fact I need to cut second argument and rename it.

I've read this article:[Using Regular Expressions to replace text in Xcode](http://roadfiresoftware.com/2013/12/replacing-regular-expressions-in-an-xcode-project/). And decided to use my "new knowledge". But something went wrong.

So: hear is the "regex" wich I've written.

[image]

Source string:

```
[self.delegate filteredTasksListContainer:self addItemWithType:type];
```

Result string :

```
[self.delegate filteredTasksListContainer_addItem:1];
```

Needed result string:

```
 [self.delegate filteredTasksListContainer_addItem:self];
```

PS:Any way, thank for attention =)

Comment: Thank, you have solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks pretty good for me, but I would try tu use `$1` instead of `\1`.

`\1` is usually used in the regex itself, rarely in the replacement pattern.